# How to attach multiple panels to a single VScrallbar in window form application?

Tags: winforms

I have 5 panels in a form and i want to add those 5 panels to a vertical scroll bar,if I scroll then it will jump from 1st panel to 2nd panel like wise.
plz suggest me a code in c#.

Thanks,
Ranjan

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the five panels inside a single panel with the single panel having `AutoScroll=true;` set.